# TreeView node highlight colour in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Using [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), when I click on a TreeView node, the highlight colour is blue. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822535/treeview-highlight-color-in-net-2-0

Answer (score 8):

It is possible if you create your own TreeView class and override the OnDrawNode method. For example, this one will highlight selected node with red color:

```
class ClassMyTreeView:TreeView
{
    public ClassMyTreeView()
    {
        this.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
    }

    protected override void OnDrawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNodeStates state = e.State;
        Font font = e.Node.NodeFont ?? e.Node.TreeView.Font;
        Color fore = e.Node.ForeColor;
        if (fore == Color.Empty) 
            fore = e.Node.TreeView.ForeColor;
        if (e.Node == e.Node.TreeView.SelectedNode)
        {
            fore = SystemColors.HighlightText;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), e.Bounds);
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, fore, Color.Red);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, font, e.Bounds, fore, Color.Red, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, font, e.Bounds, fore, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
        }
    }
}
```